# Wann können wir Präpositionen verwenden?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, word-order, dative, accusative

Welche ist die richtige Option?

1. Wir bringen ihr einen Hund.
2. Wir bringen einen Hund zu ihr.
3. Wir bringen zu ihr einen Hund.

Und warum? Dürfen wir vor dem Akkusativ den Dativ nicht schreiben?

Comment: Beide sind grammatisch korrekt. Welche Variante man nutzen sollte, hängt davon ab, was man ausdrücken will. Der Ausdruck *zu jemandem* bezieht sich auf einen Ort, an dem sich jemand befindet.

Comment: Therefore, if _ihr_ refers to Frau, then the sentence 1 is advisable and if _ihr_ refers to _Farm_, then both 1 and 2 can be used. Am I right?

Comment: @PragnyaJha No. Sentence 1 roughly implies bringing the dog to someone for ownership, even if that's only temporarily (e.g. when she's taking care of the dog for a while). Sentence 2 would put emphasis on bringing the dog to the place where "she" currently or normally is (it could mean to bring the dog to her home, even if she's not at home currently). If "ihr" refers to something inanimate (e.g. "farm"), only sentence 2 would apply -- unless you use "farm" as a personification that can "own" it's residents, then both sentences apply. (I cannot explain why, I'm just a german native ^^)

Comment: Danke für ihre Hilfe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alle drei Sätze sind grammatisch korrekt. Die Bedeutung unterscheidet sich im Einzelnen etwas. Ganz allgemein:

1. In *Wir bringen ihr einen Hund* wird eine Empfängerin angegeben, bei der es sich notwendig um eine Person handelt. Beispielsweise: *Wir bringen unserer Tante einen Hund.* Aber nicht: **Wir bringen der Wiese einen Hund.*
2. In *Wir bringen einen Hund zu ihr* wird mit *zu ihr* einfach nur angegeben, wohin der Hund gebracht wird (adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes). Hier kann alles stehen: eine Person, ein Gebäude oder irgendein anderer Ort. Beispielsweise: *Wir bringen einen Hund zur Wiese. Wir bringen einen Hund zu unserer Tante.*
3. Satz 3 ist eine zulässige Umstellung von Satz 2.

Sofern es jeweils um Personen geht, liegen die Bedeutungen sehr eng beieinander. (Siehe auch im Englischen: *to bring something to somebody* vs. *to bring somebody something* und dazu *Huddleston/Pullum*, Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, 2002, S. 309: "With verbs allowing an alternation between ditransitive and prepositional constructions, the difference between them is very largely a matter of information packaging.")

Ein feiner Unterschied ergibt sich einfach durch den Personenbezug in 1 im Gegensatz zum Ortsbezug in 2 bzw. 3: Zwar wird in beiden Fällen der Hund zur Tante hin bewegt. Allerdings impliziert *Wir bringen unserer Tante einen Hund* zusätzlich, dass die Tante den Hund in irgendeiner Weise in Empfang nimmt. Wenn Sie statt eines Hundes zum Beispiel an ein Buch denken, wird das vielleicht klarer: *Ich brachte das Buch zu meiner Mutter* trifft auch dann zu, wenn ich das Buch auf dem Dachboden im Haus meiner Mutter ablege, ohne dass sie überhaupt davon Kenntnis nimmt. *Ich brachte meiner Mutter das Buch* impliziert dagegen, dass ich meiner Mutter das Buch übergebe.

(Was mit "Dürfen wir vor dem Akkusativ den Dativ nicht schreiben?" in der Frage gemeint ist, verstehe ich leider nicht. Das müssten Sie umformulieren. In *jemandem etwas bringen* steht jedenfalls das Gebrachte im Akkusativ und der Empfänger im Dativ. In *etwas zu jemandem bringen* steht *jemandem* im Dativ, weil die Präposition *zu* den Dativ fordert.)

Comment: @Loong: Damit meine Überlegungen nicht nur in den Wind geschrieben sind, möchte ich doch einmal sehr freundlich darum bitten, mir einen Kontext zu nennen, in welchem der Satz 'wir bringen ihr einen Hund' oder 'wir bringen einen Hund zu ihr' überhaupt gesagt werden könnte. Ich meine nämlich, einen solchen Kontext gibt es nicht (siehe unten), und das würde bedeuten, dass die Sätze eigentlich falsch sind, und das sollte man dann richtigstellen. Oder wäre, nur als Beispiel, auf die Aufforderung, einen Satz mit 'gehen' zu 'bilden', auch der Satz 'der Mann geht' eine korrekte Antwort?

Answer (score -1):

Die Frage ist für mich nicht zu beantworten. Das Hauptproblem für mich besteht darin, einen Kontext zu finden, in dem einer der drei Sätze in dem Sinne "funktionieren" könnte, dass er in diesem Kontext unter normalen Umständen auch gesagt würde.

Beispiele:

> Sie ist echt zu viel allein. Wir bringen ihr jetzt einfach einen
>   Hund.

In diesem Fall würde man eher '*schenken*' sagen.

> Wir fahren in Urlaub. Zum Glück gießen die Nachbarn die Blumen, und
>   was unseren Bonny angeht, den will unsere Tante nehmen. Wir fahren da
>   jetzt hin und bringen ihr einen Hund.

Hier muss es '***den*** Hund' heißen.

> Unsere kleine Nichte hat sich so sehr ein Tier gewünscht, am liebsten
>   ein Kaninchen. Wir bringen ihr einen Hund.

Das müsste erläutert und 'gewürzt' werden, damit der Satz rund läuft: 
*Aber wir bringen (doch besser: schenken) ihr jetzt doch einen Hund, die sahen im Tiergeschäft sooo niedlich aus, da freut sie sich bestimmt.*

> Immer wieder finden wir verletzte Tiere, die bringen wir dann zu
>   meiner Schwester, die lange Jahre im Zoo gearbeitet und ein Herz für
>   Tiere hat. Wir bringen wir ihr einen Hund.

Auch hier müsste 'nachgeholfen' werden: *Heute bringen wir ihr einen Hund, mal schaun, wie sie reagiert.*

Vielleicht haben andere dabei eine leichtere Hand, ich muss mich bei diesen Sätzen sehr anstrengen, um überhaupt Kontexte zu finden, in denen ähnliche Sätze wie die angefragten passen könnten. Ein wesentliches Problem ist in diesem Fall der unbestimmte Artikel "einen (Hund)", aber auch bei dem Pronomen "ihr" ist es für mich schwer, einen sinnvollen Bezug herzustellen. Ich kann daher die Frage nicht sinnvoll beantworten.

Es handelt sich um ein grundsätzliches Problem: Sätze 'im luftleeren Raum' lassen sich nicht gut beurteilen. Andererseits fällt es natürlich Deutschlernern oft schwer, den gemeinten Kontext zu formulieren. Es wäre sinnvoll, es trotzdem zu versuchen.